# Bash script to derive n variables from until loop variable based on n iterrations is not working

Tags: bash, script, zenity

I have the following problem in a Bash script:

On execution of the script a Zenity popup box opens to ask how many date entries should occur. If for example 3 is entered then a further 3 Zenity boxes are opened up (one after another) to ask for a date entry.

From this I am able to generate two variables (`$tvar` and `$date_entry_number`). `$date_entry_number` captures the amount of dates entered and `$tvar` captures all dates entered, separated by white-space. In the case of `$date_entry_number` = 3, `$tvar` might be = `'2020-07-02'` `'2020-07-03'` `'2020-07-04'`.

What I am trying to do is create variables containing individual dates from `$tvar`, such as `$tvar1='2020-07-02'` `$tvar2='2020-07-03'` `$tvar3='2020-07-04'` base on `$date_entry_number` which could be any number. This would mean that there could be any number of dates in `$tvar`.

My thinking is that I would need a for loop as you can see in the script below but I am not sure how to do this properly. Can someone please help?

```
#!/bin/bash

date_entry_number="$(zenity --entry --text "ENTER number of date_entries:" --entry-text "1")"
        a=1 

tvar=$(until
        [[ $date_entry_number -lt $a ]]
do

date_out="$(zenity --calendar \
--title="Select a Date" \
--text="Click on a date to select that date." \
--date-format="'%G-%m-%d'")"

var="${date_out}"

echo $var

let a++

done)

echo $tvar
echo $date_entry_number

for i in {1..$date_entry_number}
do

        nvar{1..$tvar}

done

echo $nvar{1..$tvar}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create variables like `tvar1` but bash has *arrays* and that is an overall better approach.  Here is how to create an array `tvar` that contains each date as an entry:

```
#!/bin/bash    
date_entry_number="$(zenity --entry --text "ENTER number of date_entries:" --entry-text "1")"

tvar=()
a=1
until [[ $date_entry_number -lt $a ]]
do
    tvar+=("$(zenity --calendar \
        --title="Select a Date" \
        --text="Click on a date to select that date." \
        --date-format="'%G-%m-%d'")")
    let a++
done

# Show what's in the array
declare -p tvar

# Loop through the indices of the array
for i in "${!tvar[@]}"
do
    echo "date $i = ${tvar[i]}"
done
```

In the above `tvar=()` creates an array called `tvar`.

`tvar+=(...)` appends what is in the parens to the end of array `tvar`.  We use this to append each new date as it is entered.

Bash expands `${!tvar[@]}` to become a list of the array *indices*.  If `i` is an *index* in the array, as in the code above, we can access the  corresponding value with `${tvar[i]}`    It we wanted a list of the array *values*, we would use `${tvar[@]}`

For more information on the many powerful features of bash arrays, see the section in `man bash` entitled `Arrays`.

Comment: Thanks John1024, exactly what I am looking for.